# SELECT and SELECT COUNT in two tables in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

is it possible to combine SELECT and SELECT COUNT in two tables that are connected with the argument JOIN?

I want to select first and last name of customers and only count the amount of orders for each customer.

The table should display first-, lastname and the amount of orders for each customer, whereas last column should be named 'Anzahl Aufträge'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcPoe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmbhX.png)

I just added two links, so you can see, how the table should look like. :)

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Below you find my approach:

SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name,
(SELECT COUNT(orders.customer_id) AS 'Anzahl Aufträge' FROM orders)
FROM customers
JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id

Comment: You'll have to provide a table structure and sample data if you want us to help

Comment: I wanted to add pictures, but stackoverflow didn't let me add them, since I'm a new user.

Comment: Willkommen bei StackOverflow. Please read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Please post the text, not images, of your sample queries and data. Please, always, [edit] your question to provide more information rather than using comments for that purpose.

Comment: OK, I will do this in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have not given details so I must guess.

Try this:

```
       SELECT customer.customer_id, customer.givenname, customer.surname, 
              COUNT(*) number_of_orders
         FROM customer
         JOIN order ON customer.customer_id = order.customer_id
        GROUP BY customer.customer_id, customer.givenname, customer.surname
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me solve the problem. Only things I edited was the variables. 

Now it looks like this:
SELECT customers.first_name, customers.last_name, 
COUNT(*) 'Anzahl Aufträge'
FROM customers
JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
GROUP BY customers.id, customers.first_name, customers.last_name

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mean this:

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, cnt
FROM (
   SELECT customer_id, count(*) as cnt
   FROM orders
   GRUP BY customer_id
) AS q1
INNER JOIN customers as c on c.customer_id = q1.customer_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a group by to collapse the orders to the customer level:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, COUNT (*)
FROM customers JOIN orders
ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
GROUP BY customers.id;
```